# Displaying a snackbar above modal bottom sheet with dynamic height in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to display a snackbar above the modal bottom sheet, that will have a minimum possible height?

Example one: the bottom sheet has a minimum height, but the snackbar appears behind it

```
 await showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("Click me"),
      onTap: () {
        snackbars.showError(message: 'Hello');
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Example two: the snackbar appears above the bottom sheet, but the bottom sheet has no minimum possible height

```
await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ListTile(
            title: Text("Click me"),
            onTap: () {
              snackbars.showError(message: 'Hello');
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Can it be combined?